# Multiple items found. Select from drop-down or click icon to refine search on vf page onchange of lookup

Tags: visualforce, actionsupport

I'm facing this 'Lookup auto-completion conflicts' issue ([Lookup auto-completion conflicts with onchange event in Chrome and Firefox](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000sY09AAE))- 
On a Visualforce page, if you are using actionSupport and rerender on a lookup field. If the rerender is on the element that contains the lookup, it will lose the value of the "Lookup Auto-Complete" selection from the "My Recent List" and perform a search in the lookup for the text entered prior to selecting the account.

Does anyone have a workaround for this know issue?